# Twilio issue "Twilio.initialize() already called" in Android

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Bellow my code is login twilio client is working

```
public void login(final String clientName,
                          final boolean allowOutgoing,
                          final boolean allowIncoming) {
            if (loginListener != null)
                loginListener.onLoginStarted();

            this.lastClientName = clientName;
            this.lastAllowOutgoing = allowOutgoing;
            this.lastAllowIncoming = allowIncoming;

            if (!twilioSdkInited) {
                if (twilioSdkInitInProgress)
                    return;

                twilioSdkInitInProgress = true;
                Twilio.setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG);

                Twilio.initialize(context, new Twilio.InitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitialized() {

                        Log.e(TAG, "onInitialized");
                        twilioSdkInited = true;
                        twilioSdkInitInProgress = false;
                        obtainCapabilityToken(clientName, allowOutgoing, allowIncoming);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onInitialized onError :" + error.toString());
                        Log.e(TAG, " onInitialized onError : isTokenExpired is Blank");
                        twilioSdkInitInProgress = false;

                        if (loginListener != null)
                            loginListener.onLoginError(error);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {

                        Log.e(TAG, "@call finalize()");
                        if (device != null)
                            device.release();
                        if (connection != null)
                            connection.disconnect();
                        super.finalize();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "twilioSdkInited obtainCapabilityToken");
                obtainCapabilityToken(clientName, allowOutgoing, allowIncoming);
            }
```

**Below logs are error generate some time when relaunch my app.**

```
07-06 10:10:14.265 32611-32611/com.reach.communications E/NewCallScreenActivity: @call onLoginStarted
07-06 10:10:14.265 32611-32611/com.reach.communications I/PJSIP: 10:10:14.265 sip_endpoint.c !Module "mod-pjsua-log" unregistered
07-06 10:10:14.265 32611-32611/com.reach.communications I/PJSIP: 10:10:14.265 sip_endpoint.c  Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
07-06 10:10:14.265 32611-32611/com.reach.communications E/BasicPhone: onInitialized onError :java.lang.RuntimeException: Twilio.initialize() already called
07-06 10:10:14.265 32611-32611/com.reach.communications E/BasicPhone:  onInitialized onError : isTokenExpired is Blank
07-06 10:10:14.265 32611-32611/com.reach.communications E/NewCallScreenActivity: @call onLoginError :java.lang.RuntimeException: Twilio.initialize() already called
07-06 10:10:14.265 32611-32611/com.reach.communications E/NewCallScreenActivity: @Call State idle
```

How to Handle if i am getting  this error and re-login client. or How to re-initialize twilio.

> onError(Exception error)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are trying [`.release()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/Device#release__). What happens if you use the [`.shutdown()` method](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/Twilio#shutdown__)? This will terminate all connections, release all Device objects, and release any resources used by the SDK.

Then you can safely call `.initialize()` again before the next call.

Additionally, you can use [`.isInitialized()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/Twilio#isInitialized__) to determine if the Client is ready or not.

Please let me know if any of these changes help.